# ServerSocket constructor in laymans terms

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

What would this statement do:

```
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(4646);
```

Please explain in layman terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement effectively tells the JVM to listen on port specified (4646) for incoming connections. By itself it doesn't mean anything since you will have to take incoming connections to that port and use them to build normal `Socket` objects that will be then used for ingoing/outgoing data.

You could say that the `ServerSocket` is the object through which real TCP sockets between clients and the server are created. When you create it, the JVM hooks to the operating system telling it to dispatch connections that arrive on that port to your program.

What you typically do is something like:

```
public AcceptThread extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4646);
    while (true) {
      Socket newConnection = ss.accept();
      ClientThread thread = new ClientThread(newConnection);
      thread.start();
    }
  }
}
```

So that you will accept incoming connections and open a thread for them.

Comment: @ Jack
 Let me verify,ServerSocket(4646) books the port 4646 of server.Now all the incoming connection requests from client will be on port 4646.Is that so?

Comment: "Now all the incoming connection requests from client will be on port 4646": this doesn't mean anything. After opening the port in LISTEN mode (take a look at TCP/IP rfc) the port will be available to clients that will try to contact THAT SPECIFIC PORT. Otherwise the operating system would refuse any attempt from a client to connect to 4646 instead that dispatching it to the JVM.

Comment: @ Jack `Socket newConnection = ss.accept();`,here accept returns a socket object,that is bound to 4646 port of server and some numbered port of client.Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is possible thanks to the multiplexing technique used by TCP/IP protocol which uses both IP addresses and both ports (client and server) to distinguish a specific TCP connection.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [`ServerSocket` Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int%29):

> Creates a server socket, bound to the specified port.

What's a server socket?

> This class implements server sockets. A server socket waits for requests to come in over the network. It performs some operation based on that request, and then possibly returns a result to the requester.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ServerSocket(int port) throws IOException
```

[documentation:](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int%29)

> Creates a server socket, bound to the
>   specified port. A port of 0 creates a
>   socket on any free port.

Answer (score 0):

That would bind your ServerSocket to port 4646 on the local machine.

You could then accept sockets on this connection with

```
// pick up server side of the socket
Socket s = ss.accept();
```

Now, your client can connect to your server, establishing a socket connection, like this

```
// pick up client side of the socket, this is in a different program (probably)
Socket connectionToServer = new Socket("myserver",4646);
```

Comment: @user628662 A ServerSocket is what your server uses to tell the world "I am willing to accept connections! Go ahead and connect to me!"

Comment: If you don't know what a network socket is read this http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html and maye some more ...

Comment: @ glowcoder what do u mean by "you could then accept sockets on this connection"? please explain

Comment: A Socket is what you use to connect to something. If I want to connect to a server, I have to open a socket to that server. Think of socket as a wire running through the internet that I can use to connect my program directly to your program (in that relationship, we call my program a client and your program a server.)